# Zf2 file upload by jQuery File Upload - file was not found

Tags: php, file-upload, zend-framework2, file-transfer

when I use jQuery File Upload I have error during ajax upload.

In controller:

```
$adapter = new \Zend\File\Transfer\Adapter\Http();
$adapter->isValid();
```

or

```
$adapter->receive();
```

Both methotds returns "File [file name] was not found"

dump from $_FILES:

```
Array
(
    [files] => Array
        (
            [name] => Penguins.jpg
            [type] => image/jpeg
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpwQoG2L
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 777835
        )

)
```

If I use move_uploaded_file in the same place all works

ZF2 v2.2.4

What is wrong?

Comment: Did you read the notes and look at the examples here http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zend.form.file-upload.html ?